# Why does this define a stochastic differential equation.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I'm reading about [stochastic differential equations](http://ft-sipil.unila.ac.id/dbooks/AN%20INTRODUCTION%20TO%20STOCHASTIC%20DIFFERENTIAL%20EQUATIONS%20VERSION%201.2.pdf). On page 4 of this mini course the stochastic differential equation is defined as follows:

> Now return to the general case of equation $(1)$, write $\dfrac{d}{dt}$ instead of the dot: $$\dfrac{dX(t)}{dt} = b(X(t))dt + B(X(t))\dfrac{dW}{dt},$$ and finally multiply by $dt$:
>
> $$(SDE)\,\,\,\begin{cases}dX(t) = b(X(t))dt + B(X(t))dW(t)\\
> X(0)  = x_0.\end{cases}$$

**Question 1:** Why does this define a differential equation? As far as I can tell there is no longer a derivative in this system.

On page 5 Ito's formula is introduced as follows:

> Assume $n=1$ and $X(\cdot)$ solves the SDE $$dX = b(X)dt + dW$$ Suppose next that $u:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a given smooth function. We ask: what stochastic differential equation does $$Y(t) := u(X(t))$$ solve? Offhand, we would guess from $(3)$ that $$dY = u'dX = u'bdt + u'dW,$$ according to the chain rule, where $' = \dfrac{d}{dx}$. This is wrong however!

**Question 2:** Apparently it's wrong anyway, but how would you arrive at $dY = u'dX = u'bdt + u'dW$ at all? If $dX = b(X)dt + dW$ and $Y = u(X(t))$ then I would expect $dY = du(X(t))$.

Comment: You are actually asking that somebody writes here the one or two first chapters of some lectures on the subject. Sorry but this is not what the site can provide.

Comment: It seems that you read only a few first pages which are in the section "Some Heuristics". To understand SDEs you will need to learn about Brownian Motion (BM) first, the notes from the link seem decent. It is good that you have questions at the beginning, then if you follow the course you should be able to answer them later on. Regarding question 2: if $Y(t) = u(X(t))$ then $\frac{dY}{dt} = \frac{dX(t)}{dt}u^{\prime}(X(t))$ now we can simplify the notation to $dY = u^{\prime}dX$ where $u^{\prime}\equiv u^{\prime}(X(t))$.This would work in classical calculus, here it is not the case due to BM.